# How to list all the commands that executed on a pulled Docker image?

Tags: linux, docker

I'm currently studying Docker for the lab use. Imagine this is my situation: I created a Docker image and then pushed it to the Docker Hub with my username(e.g. myname/lab1). Later on, my friend pulled my image and then commit some changes on it, then pushed it to the Docker Hub with his username (his/lab1). 
My question is, assume I'm able to pull his the image (his/lab1) which is built upon my original image, how can I find/list all the changes my friend made to my original image?

Many thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`docker history <image_name/id>`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/history/)

```
▶ docker history ubuntu
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
f7b3f317ec73        5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/bash"]            0 B
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c mkdir -p /run/systemd && echo '...   7 B
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c sed -i 's/^#\s*\(deb.*universe\...   2.76 kB
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*          0 B
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c set -xe   && echo '#!/bin/sh' >...   745 B
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:141408db9037263...   117 MB
```

Add `--no-trunc` in order to see the complete command (CREATED BY column).

However, IMHO the ideal way to work with your friend should be maintaining a versioned Dockerfile and see the changes there.

---

If you don't track your changes with Dockerfile, and you use `docker commit` instead, it is more difficult to see the changes that a layer add. There is a proposal regarding this: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/12641, that is still an Open Issue, as of Jun/2017.

Comment: Hey Robert, thanks for your help! But the "history" command does not work for me.... My problem is if my friend (say, Tom) pulled my centos image (me/lab1) from Docker Hub, run a container upon it, then delete a user, and then commit the change and push it to his own account with name Tom/lab1. Now, if I pull the Tom/lab1 to my local machine, the "history" command does not return the "userdel" command Tom executed on my original image.

Comment: Docker doesn't know about the commands run interactively in the shell. It only knows about the command used to start the container (which would likely just be the shell in your case) or the commands from the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Let me see if there is some clue somewhere

Comment: @stackoverheat please see my edition (after horizontal line)